# How to download repository in zip with github API

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, web, github-api

I am developing a web app with laravel and angularjs (I am new to both), in which when you click on a button, you must download a github repository (or clone it)

I know that if I add this `"href='/:owner/:repo/archive/master.zip'` to an anchor tag, it can be downloaded, but I don't want the folder named" repo-master "

I have an idea to clone the repository using `exec("git clone clone_url");` and then somehow compress it and link it to the web, but I don't think it's the best solution.

EDIT:

The problem of downloading the .zip as "repo-master.zip" is not only the name of the zip, but the folder inside, as it calls "repo-master" as well.

I solved it like this:

```
$module = Module::findOrFail($id);
$clone = $module->link_repo.".git";
$name_module = $module->name;
$zip_file = $name_module.'.zip'; // Name of our archive to download
exec("git clone ". $clone);
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$path = "C:/laragon/www/project/public/".$name_module;
$files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
 // We're skipping all subfolders
    if (!$file->isDir()) {
        $filePath     = $file->getRealPath();
        // extracting filename with substr/strlen
        $relativePath = $name_module."/". substr($filePath, strlen($path) + 1);

        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
     }
}
$zip->close();
```

[Reference](https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-zip-archive-with-files-and-download-it-in-laravel/)

Comment: You can use the `download` attribute on the anchor tag to set the filename, i.e. `<a href="/example" download="filename.zip">Download</a>`

Comment: @MartinBean, I think they're referring to the name of the file that gets downloaded for the user, not the link text.

Comment: Try it but it does not work, still download the zip with its original name, but the problem is that the folder inside the zip is the one that should be called as the repository, just as it happens when cloning

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, that’s why I said you can specify the filename with the `download` parameter on the anchor tag.

Comment: @MartinBean, sorry, poor reading comprehension on my part.